# Make directory writable on /var/www/html (Centos 7)

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, centos

This below question are [related to my question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617580/codeigniter-captcha-not-showing-up-image/37620004#37620004).

I got following error when I went to generate an image on a particular directory:

```
imagejpeg(/var/www/html/assets/files/captcha/1465029891.5357.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I want to make the directory are writable and I’ve been use this command below to make the directory are writable but it doesn’t impact at all.

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/assets/files/captcha
chmod 755 /var/www/html/assets/files/captcha
```

Below is when I run the `ps -aux|grep -i httpd`:

```
root     30846  0.0  0.1 423604 17476 ?        Ss   15:43   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   30848  0.0  0.1 424024 12892 ?        S    15:43   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   30849  0.0  0.0 423736 10032 ?        S    15:43   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   30850  0.0  0.0 423912 11680 ?        S    15:43   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   30851  0.0  0.0 423736  9280 ?        S    15:43   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   30852  0.0  0.0 423736  9276 ?        S    15:43   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   30854  0.0  0.0 423736  9268 ?        S    15:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   30855  0.0  0.0 423736  9032 ?        S    15:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   30856  0.0  0.0 423736  9032 ?        S    15:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root     30860  0.0  0.0 112648   988 pts/1    S+   15:51   0:00 grep --color=auto -i httpd
```

I’ve checked on the server and it’s run by Apache, I’ve changed the user, group and changed the permissions but still get above error. Which part did I miss?

Answer (score -1):

I've found a clue regarding my issue, because i use the CentOS 7, there is some security call SE Linux (Security Enhance Linux), it's hidden firewall for Centos.

I'm following this article and my captcha working correctly right know, because they can write into the particular directory.

https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/

---- Update ----

sudo chown apache:apache -R /data/www/html/sites/mysite
cd /data/www/html/sites/mysite

find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;

find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;

sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite -R

sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite/logs -R
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite/uploads -R

Comment: `chcon` would not survive or persist if system ever does relabelling. So better use `semanage -fcontext` and then `restorecon`

Comment: so it's not permanent ?, currently it's working i hope it will still working...

Comment: Yes changes made via `chcon` are not permanent and they are lost upon system relabelling or running `restorecon` command. [Read further](http://linuxfuse.blogspot.in/2015/03/difference-between-chcon-and-semanage.html) and update your answer so that it provides more accurate and reliable information

Comment: In general, it's better to make posts self-contained.  Links break, in which case your answer would be just a clue.  Include the essential information within the post and use the link for reference.  [from Low Quality Post review queue](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/540689)